# Spaces and Expose Overview using the 2nd Monitor

Tags: spaces, desktop, expose, defaults

I have two monitors, and 9 (3x3) virtual desktops. When I invoke the Spaces overview mode of expose, everything gets pulled onto the primary display. It creates one overview with 3x3 desktops, although each desktop is a weird shape of two rectangles touching and offset, representing the two monitors.

I would much prefer to have both desktops used for this view, with a 3x3 display of the primary spaces on the primary display, and a 2nd 3x3 display of the secondary desktops on the second display.

Does anyone know of a `defaults` command or 3rd party app that supports this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it’s not possible to show the Spaces Overview on both screens. It will always be shown in the primary display and the other will fade to black. I haven’t come across any utility that does that. [Hyperspaces](https://hyperspacesapp.com) is nice, but it doesn’t do that. Although if you really use spaces, I’d recommend you give it a look. Read their blog and possibly ask the author if such thing would be possible for future versions. He’s working on version 2.0 at the moment and you never know… :)

Answer (score 0):

Mission Control does this in Lion!